# Laravel dingo api group by multiple domains

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

Is it possible to group dingo api routes with multiple domains? For example

```
$api->group(['domain' => ['something.com', 'anotherexample.com]], function ($api) {

  // My routes

});
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to repeat code.

```
$callback = function() {};

Route::group(['domain' => 'foo.bar.dev'], $callback);
Route::group(['domain' => 'foo.bar'], $callback);
```

But we have one more micro solution

```
Route::macro("domain", function(array $domains, \Closure $definition) {
    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        Route::group(['domain' => $domain], $definition);
    }
});
Route::domain(['foo.bar.dev', 'foo.bar'], function($route) {
    // Do stuff
});
```